# Clojure - Function that returns all the indices of a vector of vectors

Tags: clojure

If I have a vector `[[[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]] [[10 11] [12 13]] [[14] [15]]]`

How can I return the positions of each element in the vector?

For example 1 has index `[0 0 0]`, 2 has index `[0 0 1]`, etc

I want something like

```
(some-fn [[[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]] [[10 11] [12 13]] [[14] [15]]] 1)
=> [0 0 0]
```

I know that if I have a vector `[1 2 3 4]`, I can do `(.indexOf [1 2 3 4] 1) => 0` but how can I extend this to vectors within vectors.

Thanks

Comment: Nitpick: the name [`some-fn`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some-fn) is already taken, so you might want to use a different name in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this.

Unlike Asthor's answer it works for any nesting depth (until it runs out of stack). Their answer will give the indices of all items that match, while mine will return the first one. Which one you want depends on the specific use-case.

```
(defn indexed [coll]
  (map-indexed vector coll))

(defn nested-index-of [coll target]
  (letfn [(step [indices coll]
            (reduce (fn [_ [i x]]
                      (if (sequential? x)
                        (when-let [result (step (conj indices i) x)]
                          (reduced result))
                        (when (= x target)
                          (reduced (conj indices i)))))
                    nil, (indexed coll)))]
    (step [] coll)))

(def x [[[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]] [[10 11] [12 13]] [[14] [15]]])

(nested-index-of x 2) ;=> [0 0 1]

(nested-index-of x 15) ;=> [2 1 0]
```

Edit: Target never changes, so the inner step fn doesn't need it as an argument.

Edit 2: Cause I'm procrastinating here, and recursion is a nice puzzle, maybe you wanted the indices of all matches.

You can tweak my first function slightly to carry around an accumulator.

```
(defn nested-indices-of [coll target]
  (letfn [(step [indices acc coll]
            (reduce (fn [acc [i x]]
                      (if (sequential? x)
                        (step (conj indices i) acc x)
                        (if (= x target)
                          (conj acc (conj indices i))
                          acc)))
                    acc, (indexed coll)))]
    (step [] [] coll)))

(def y [[[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]] [[10 11] [12 13]] [[14] [15 [16 17 4]]]])

(nested-indices-of y 4) ;=> [[0 1 0] [2 1 1 2]]
```

Comment: Very nice so gave +1. Much more general answer than mine which is just focused on solving this problem and I feel if you reach this point in your logic there is probably some better data structures that can be used to get there. 
However, for your answer, wouldn't it be better to use map instead of reduce? Then you could skip the ignore parameter.

Comment: Thanks :) I used reduce to bail out early with reduced, off-hand I don't really see how you'd use map. And, yeah, at this point I would take a step back and look at the bigger picture to see if maybe I could find a way to not have all this nesting in the first place.

Comment: I think of the _ argument as kinda the nil that is carried around and returned if not-found.

Comment: Didn't consider the no value found scenario. And you are right, map would probably be quite clunky.

Answer (score 2):

and one more solution with zippers:

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as z])

(defn find-in-vec [x data] 
  (loop [curr (z/vector-zip data)]
    (cond (z/end? curr) nil
          (= x (z/node curr)) (let [path (rseq (conj (z/path curr) x))]
                                (reverse (map #(.indexOf %2 %1) path (rest path))))
          :else (recur (z/next curr)))))

user> (find-in-vec 11 data)
(1 0 1)
user> (find-in-vec 12 data)
(1 1 0)
user> (find-in-vec 18 data)
nil
user> (find-in-vec 8 data)
(0 2 1)
```

the idea is to make a depth-first search for an item, and then reconstruct a path to it, indexing it.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors within vectors are no different to `int`s within vectors:

```
(.indexOf [[[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]] [[10 11] [12 13]] [[14] [15]]] [[14] [15]])
;;=> 2
```

The above might be a bit difficult to read, but `[[14] [15]]` is the third element.

Comment: Ideally I want something where `(some-function [[[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]] [[10 11] [12 13]] [[14] [15]]] 1) => [0 0 0]`  It's getting the `[0 0 0]` vector out that I am struggling with

Comment: I get it now. What position is 1 at? It is at the 0th position within the 0th vector within the 0th vector. A recursive function would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
(defn indexer [vec number]
  (for [[x set1] (map-indexed vector vec) 
        [y set2] (map-indexed vector set1) 
        [z val] (map-indexed vector set2) 
        :when (= number val)]
   [x y z]))
```

Written directly into here so not tested. Giving more context on what this would be used for might make it easier to give a good answer as this feels like something you shouldn't end up doing in Clojure.

You can also try and flatten the vectors in some way

Answer (score 0):

An other solution to find the path of every occurrences of a given number.

Usually with functional programming you can go for broader, general, elegant, bite size solution. You will always be able to optimize using language constructs or techniques as you need (tail recursion, use of accumulator, use of lazy-seq, etc)

```
(defn indexes-of-value [v coll]
  (into []
        (comp (map-indexed #(if (== v %2) %1))
              (remove nil?))
        coll))

(defn coord' [v path coll]
  (cond
    ;; node is a leaf: empty or coll of numbers
    (or (empty? coll)
        (number? (first coll)))
    (when-let [indexes (seq (indexes-of-value v coll))]
      (map #(conj path %) indexes))

    ;; node is branch: a coll of colls
    (coll? (first coll))
    (seq (sequence (comp (map-indexed vector)
                         (mapcat #(coord' v (conj path (first %)) (second %))))
                   coll))))

(defn coords [v coll] (coord' v [] coll))
```

Execution examples:

```
(def coll [[2 1] [] [7 8 9] [[] [1 2 2 3 2]]])
(coords 2 coll)
=> ([0 0] [3 1 1] [3 1 2] [3 1 4])
```

As a bonus you can write a function to test if paths are all valid:

```
(defn valid-coords? [v coll coords]
  (->> coords
       (map #(get-in coll %))
       (remove #(== v %))
       empty?))
```

and try the solution with input generated with [clojure.spec](https://clojure.org/guides/spec):

```
(s/def ::leaf-vec (s/coll-of nat-int? :kind vector?))
(s/def ::branch-vec (s/or :branch (s/coll-of ::branch-vec :kind vector?
                                                          :min-count 1)
                          :leaf ::leaf-vec))
(let [v 1
      coll (first (gen/sample (s/gen ::branch-vec) 1))
      res (coords v coll)]
  (println "generated coll: " coll)
  (if-not (valid-coords? v coll res)
    (println "Error:" res)
    :ok))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a function that can recursively search for a target value, keeping track of the indexes as it goes:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(defn index-impl
  [idxs data tgt]
  (apply glue
    (for [[idx val] (zip (range (count data)) data)]
      (let [idxs-curr (append idxs idx)]
           (if (sequential? val)
             (index-impl idxs-curr val tgt)
             (if (= val tgt)
               [{:idxs idxs-curr :val val}]
               [nil]))))))

(defn index [data tgt]
  (keep-if not-nil? (index-impl [] data tgt)))

(dotest
  (let [data-1 [1 2 3]
        data-2 [[1 2 3]
                [10 11]
                []]
        data-3 [[[1 2 3]
                 [4 5 6]
                 [7 8 9]]
                [[10 11]
                 [12 13]]
                [[20]
                 [21]]
                [[30]]
                [[]]]
  ]
    (spyx (index data-1 2))
    (spyx (index data-2 10))
    (spyx (index data-3 13))
    (spyx (index data-3 21))
    (spyx (index data-3 99))
  ))
```

with results:

```
(index data-1  2) => [{:idxs [1], :val 2}]
(index data-2 10) => [{:idxs [1 0], :val 10}]
(index data-3 13) => [{:idxs [1 1 1], :val 13}]
(index data-3 21) => [{:idxs [2 1 0], :val 21}]
(index data-3 99) => []
```

If we add repeated values we get the following:

```
data-4 [[[1 2 3]
         [4 5 6]
         [7 8 9]]
        [[10 11]
         [12  2]]
        [[20]
         [21]]
        [[30]]
        [[2]]]

(index data-4 2) => [{:idxs [0 0 1], :val 2} 
                     {:idxs [1 1 1], :val 2}
                     {:idxs [4 0 0], :val 2}]
```

Comment: I think this answer contains the best algorithm of all the answers (a recursive function with a `for` comprehension finding all matching indices), but it's hard to upvote it because I can't verify that it works as intended without futzing with tupelo. Everything you need to do is readily accessible in clojure.core; why depend on tupelo?